# Search for all `.xls` files on Ubuntu from command-line?

Tags: ubuntu, file-search

How would you search for all `.xls` files in the current directory and in all of the subdirectories below the current directory in Ubuntu from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> find . -type f -name '*.xls'